# how do I return values from an async each function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I know this is a common problem for people, and I've looked up some guides and looked at the docs, but I'm not understanding what is happening, and would love some help.

Here is the controller function I am working on:

```
exports.appDetail = function (req, res) {
  appRepo.findWithId(req.params.id, (err, myApp) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    getDeviceData(myApp.devices, (err, myDeviceData) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(myDeviceData) + '  ||  myDeviceData')
      // construct object to be returned
      let appsDataObject = {
        name: myApp.name,
        user_id: myApp.user_id,
        devices: myDeviceData,
        permissions: myApp.permissions
      }
      return res.status(200).send(appsDataObject)
    })
  })
}

// write async function here
const getDeviceData = function (devices, callback) {
  let devicesDataArray = []
  async.each(devices, function (device, cb) {
    deviceRepo.findById(new ObjectID(device), (err, myDevice) => {
      if (err) {
        cb(err)
      }
      // get device data, push to devices array
      let deviceObj = {
        name: myDevice.name,
        version: myDevice.version
      }
      devicesDataArray.push(deviceObj)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(devicesDataArray) + '  ||  devicesDataAray after obj push')
    })
    cb(null, devicesDataArray)
  }, function (err) {
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if (err) console.log(err)
  })
  callback(null, devicesDataArray)
}
```

I originally wrote this with a for loop and a callback, but I think it was impossible to do that way (I'm not sure about that though).  If there is a better way to make an asynchronous loop, please let me know.

On ~line 8 there is a log statement `myDeviceData`.  This should be returning the data I want through a callback, but this log statement always comes back empty.  And since the other log statements show that the data is being formatted correctly, the problem must be with returning the data I need through the callback of `getDeviceData()`.  Presumably, the `callback(null, devicesDataArray)` should do this.

I'm not understanding how these async functions are supposed to work, clearly. Can someone please help me understand how I should get values from these async.each functions? Thank you.

EDIT:
I refactored the code to try and make it clearer and approach the problem better, and I have pinpointed where the problem is.  At the beginning the this function I define `devicesDataArray` as an empty array, and at the end I return the array.  Everything inside happens as it should, but I don't know how to tell the return to wait until the array isn't empty, if that makes sense,  Here is the new code:

```
let getData = async function (devices) {
  let devicesDataArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    deviceRepo.findById(new ObjectID(devices[i]), async (err, myDevice) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(myDevice) + '  ||  myDevice')
      let deviceObj = await {
        name: myDevice.name,
        version: myDevice.version
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(deviceObj) + '  ||  deviceObj')
      await devicesDataArray.push(deviceObj)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(devicesDataArray) + '  ||  devicesDataArray after push')
    })
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(devicesDataArray) + '  ||  devicesDataArray before return')
  return Promise.all(devicesDataArray)  // problem is here.
}
```

Any help towards understanding this is appreciated.

Comment: Brian, your callback will execute immediately as your loop is async. Really you want to the outside method to be async, perform your loop sync internally and then execute the callback.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Can you explain what you mean by "perform your loop sync internally and then execute the callback"?  I'm not certain how to apply that to the code.

Comment: I will add some more color to my answer later this evening. Sorry I need to leave the office.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

The `Promise` object is returned immediately and we perform our async code inside there.

```js
const someFuncThatTakesTime = () => {
  // Here is our ASYNC 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // In here we are synchronous again. 
    const myArray = [];  
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      myArray.push(x);
    }
    
    // Here is the callback    
    setTimeout(() => resolve(myArray), 3000);  
  });
};

someFuncThatTakesTime().then(array => console.log(array));
```

Comment: I couldn't get this style of approach to work, returning a new Promise, and explicitly resolving it.  I've edited my original post above to include code that attempts to use async/await.

Answer (score 0):

first, I would prefer to avoid using callback because it will make your code unreadable, 
also you can handle `async` using javascript methods without any needs to use other modules.
the reason for your problem is   your async.each function executed without waiting what it has inside
and you have here `deviceRepo.findById` which is async function and need to wait for it 
I refactored your code using async await  and I wish this will simplify the problem

```
 exports.appDetail = function async(req, res) {
  try {
    const myApp = await appRepo.findWithId(req.params.id)
    const myDeviceData = await getDeviceData(myApp.device)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myDeviceData) + '  ||  myDeviceData')
    // construct object to be returned
    let appsDataObject = {
      name: myApp.name,
      user_id: myApp.user_id,
      devices: myDeviceData,
      permissions: myApp.permissions
    }
    return res.status(200).send(appsDataObject)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

}

// write async function here
const getDeviceData = function async(devices) {
  let devicesDataArrayPromises = devices.map(async(device)=>{
  const myDevice=  await deviceRepo.findById(new ObjectID(device))
        let deviceObj = {
        name: myDevice.name,
        version: myDevice.version
      }
  return deviceObj
  })
  const devicesDataArray = await Promise.all(devicesDataArrayPromises)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(devicesDataArray) + '  ||  devicesDataAray after obj push')
return  devicesDataArray
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't run.  A number of the `await` instances raise errors, saying that `await` can only be used inside of an async function.  I've edited the original post above  so that it is using await async, but it still is not working,

Comment: check that you added `async` to the decleration here `exports.appDetail = function async(req, res) { ...`
and your edits  here `      let deviceObj = await {
        name: myDevice.name,
        version: myDevice.version
      }
` and here `
      await devicesDataArray.push(deviceObj)
` are useless , also remember when you call `getData` you need to use await 
so `await getData(devices)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've been looking over it and everything make sense.  I think this is the correct approach, but two of the functions I call are functions that take callbacks, but in the code here they are like this:`const myApp = await appRepo.findWithId(req.params.id)`. Is it possible to mix callbacks and promises?

Comment: yes, it is, but will add complexity to your code and make it hard to read, 
what I suggest is to wrap any call back function with a Promise ,so you can use your callback function as a Promise 
`const callbackFunc =(params,cb)=>{cb(params)}; ` you can transform it to  this
`const promiseFunc = (parms)=>new Promise((resolve,reject)=>callbackFunc(parms,(result)=>resolve(result))`
then  `const result = await promiseFunc(params) `